# What are my licensing obligations when publishing a container built on ubuntu?

Tags: license, container

I'm part of a group that publishes workloads as containers, and we want to use Ubuntu as a base layer. We've reviewed the licensing terms for Ubuntu [here](https://ubuntu.com/licensing), however it is still unclear if Ubuntu itself has any licensing obligations. We plan to publish onto Docker Hub and AWS Marketplace.

Can we publish a container image that is built on top of Ubuntu?

Comment: This is a user support site, you may get better legal protection seeking *official* advice, than that of users (which form the majority of the users of this site). Why not send an email to the legal@ email address found on your provided link.

Comment: That's a good point, and I'll pursue that option as well.

Answer (score 0):

Not a lawyer, but as I understand it, you don't publish the base layer. The thing you upload are the layers above with just your additions. This shouldn't be different from any other third party software running on Ubuntu.

Comment: I've heard this before, and it would solve my problem, but I've yet to see documentation for it. Do you know where I can find proof?